# Using svg images in IEEEAccess

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to import svg images to the [IEEEAccess template](https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/preparing-your-article/)
which can be found on the link under the **IEEE Access Required Article Templates**.

My problem is that when i use the command:

```
\usepackage{svg}
```

the document loses it's title, Section titles, annotation of Figures etc.
All of these are custom for the current template.
Why is this happening?
Does anybody know a workaround?
I am also using Overleaf.

Comment: behind the scenes, the svg package will use inkscape to convert the svg to pdf and include those. You could convert the images yourself and include the pdf instead.

Comment: convert svg to pdf and upload the pdf?

Comment: Yes, I think this would be the easiest solution.